# Catch window open event from iframe (jquery)

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, window

I have an iframe (not on the same domain) on my page. In this, there are intern-links and extern-links (with target blank). For the extern-links, I would apply a javascript function to transform the destination URL.

I would like to catch the window open event (or other event ?) which allows me to have the destination URL. 
I have tried with JQquery : click event on "a" object but it doesn't work (because iframe is not on same domain) and with a lot of others events... but nothing works !

Have you some ideas ?

For information, my javascript function rewrites the URL with Xiti parameters and does a window.open(newURL, '_blank')

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're trying to do is being blocked due to security restrictions. Have you considered adding your event handler into the page that's inside the iframe?

Comment: I can't modify the content of the iframe because I have different content from several origins.

Comment: If you don't own the pages inside the iframe, then you probably can't modify them with javascript. If browsers allowed this, it would be an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: It's exactly what I think too. I hoped a trick to catch an "open window" event or something like that... But after a lot of tests, I haven't found nothing.